# Windows mobile getting incorrect value after access webservice

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-services, .net-3.5, windows-mobile

I have a webservice that should return a string in the 'VarietyCode' field.

When I use the WS through an application of type 'Console', the value returned is correct, but when consumed through a windows mobile application, the value is incorrect.

Below are images of both applications consuming WS.

Console Source + Result
[image: 1]

App Source + Result

[image: 2]

Someone have anyidea about whats happens? The APP that was consume WS was developed with VisualStudio2008 and .NET 3.5 CE.

*Hey guys, i can't figure out why this problem happens. I did some test using WCFTestClient and i have the follow results:*

*- With VisualStudio2008 WCFTestClient: I got a deserialize error.
 - With VisualStudio2010 WCFTestClient or Higher: The WS call works fine.*

*My solution was change the return type from complex object to a JSON string. To do this I add JSONConvert to deserialize the callback, and I created a ViewModel in app side like the old complex type using in WS.*

Comment: What is the second parameter (542, true) while calling the web service method from the mobile App? You are not invoking the same method, you should also check what is returned from the web service since it is obvious that the Id = 176647 is not there and the default is returned by Linq.

Comment: Looks like you are using an overload of `GetGmCProductionDetailsNoIncludes` as stated by Oguz. In the console you pass **542** whilst in the mobile app you pass **542, True**.

Comment: I saw that, but in app i haven't a method GetGmCProductionDetailsNoIncludes  without the second parameter. The stranger is that in WS the method don't have an second parameter. I'll try pass false in the second parameter to see what's happens.